# How to get only the first records from each day?

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

How to get only the first records from each day?

```
id | name | date
1  | aaa  | 2018-05-10
2  | bbb  | 2018-05-10
3  | ccc  | 2018-05-10
4  | ddd  | 2018-05-11
5  | eee  | 2018-05-11
6  | fff  | 2018-05-13
```

I would like to receive:

```
1  | aaa  | 2018-05-10
4  | ddd  | 2018-05-11
6  | fff  | 2018-05-13
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: First according to what? Lowest id, or name in alphabetic order?

Comment: @jarlh I think its according to date column

Comment: What code have you written? What results did you obtain? What is wrong with the results?

Comment: U need to select `MIN(ID)` `Grouped by Date`

Comment: MySQL, but I can use also PostgreSQL. Yes, it must use the date column.

Comment: Make up your mind.  The dbms you use will affect what code you get.  It's dbms dependent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If ID is Pk,this query can work on PostgreSQL and MySql

Writing subquery to get `MIN` id by `date` in the table,then self join

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM (
  SELECT MIN(ID) minId
  FROM T1 
  GROUP BY date
) t inner join t1 on t.minid = t1.id
```

*sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9a48d7/4*

Answer (score 1):

For Postgres there is a more efficient solution:

```
select distinct on (id) id, name, date
from the_table
order by id, date;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE T1
    (id int, name varchar2(3), dat timestamp)
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO T1 (id, name, dat)
         VALUES (1, 'aaa', '10-May-2018 12:00:00 AM')
    INTO T1 (id, name, dat)
         VALUES (2, 'bbb', '10-May-2018 12:00:00 AM')
    INTO T1 (id, name, dat)
         VALUES (3, 'ccc', '10-May-2018 12:00:00 AM')
    INTO T1 (id, name, dat)
         VALUES (4, 'ddd', '11-May-2018 12:00:00 AM')
    INTO T1 (id, name, dat)
         VALUES (5, 'eee', '11-May-2018 12:00:00 AM')
    INTO T1 (id, name, dat)
         VALUES (6, 'fff', '13-May-2018 12:00:00 AM')
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

> Query -

```
select id, name, dat from (
select id, name, dat, dense_rank() over (partition by dat order by id) as rnk
from t1
  ) where rnk = 1;



ID  NAME    DAT
1   aaa 2018-05-10 00:00:00.0
4   ddd 2018-05-11 00:00:00.0
6   fff 2018-05-13 00:00:00.0
```

Comment: MySQL (or perhaps Postgresql) is now said. Will this query work?

Comment: Sorry, this is Oracle specific

Comment: Well, you're the one who spent time and effort writing an answer for another dbms, just because OP didn't care to tell which one...